# Produce empty Plot with ggsurvplot

Tags: r, survival, survminer

Is it possible to produce an empty plot with `survminer::ggsurvplot`?

Here is an example. Say, dependent on the number of groups, I want to create a ggsurvplot. Figure 1 shows an example with 2 groups. If there are no groups, the desired outcome would be Figure 2 (here created by Paint).

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

set.seed(123)
df=data.frame(gender=c(rep("group1", 10), rep("group2", 10)), value=c(rnorm(10,mean = 2), rnorm(10,mean = 3)))
fit = surv_fit(Surv(value) ~ gender, data = df)
p = ggsurvplot(fit, data = df,  surv.median.line = "none")
```

[image: Figure 1]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be a clever fox and set colors, i.e. `palette=` to white.

```
ggsurvplot(fit, data=df, surv.median.line="none", palette=rep("white", 2), legend="none")
```

[image]